# The optimal solution for clicking on the mobile version

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

Recently, I read an article on a "good" system(IOS 9) and about the number of errors in the safari.Event `click` didn't work.I found many solutions to this problem, but all work in their own way and each has its own disadvantages. Can you tell what is the best solution for hanging an event click on an item? To work only on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use jQuery mobile's **vclick** event. This event handler simulates the "onclick" event handler on mobile devices.

Take a look to the [documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/).

I hope this helps you!

Comment: `jQuery('#from-from-txt,#to-to-txt,#to-from-txt,#from-to-txt').on("vclick",function (event) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } );` didn't work(